# Going to USA from France with my girlfriend

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, h1-visa, family

I'm looking for an H-1B Visa and it is mentioned that `immediate family members (spouse and children under 21 years of age)` can get a H-4 Visa.

I've been living with my girlfriend for 3 years but we don't want to get married yet, do you think she can still get this H-4 Visa ? Is the French PACS considered as married ?

If not, do you have any ideas on how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually wasn't able to find the information direcly from USCIS but [University of Washington](http://ap.washington.edu/ahr/administrators/international-scholars/h1b-visas/h4-family/) gives a clarification on the subject:

> Domestic partners are not eligible for H-4 status but may apply for B-2 visas.

In addition there is an [FAQ from the State department](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/DOMA/DOMA%20FAQs.pdf) referred to by [Law and Border FAQ](http://lawandborder.com/supreme-court-ruling-makes-same-sex-spouses-eligible-for-immigration-benefits/#10_Does_a_civil_union_or_domestic_partnership_count) that states

> **Q: I am in a civil union or domestic partnership; will this be treated the same as a marriage?**
>
> A: At this time, only a relationship legally considered to be a marriage in the jurisdiction where it took place establishes eligibility as a spouse for immigration purposes.

So you can look at @littleadv answer about the B2 Visa.

Comment: I believe this to be true. I have a friend who got married for this reason.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Thanks @JeremyMiles for this anecdote, I may need to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

No, she can't. "Spouse" means **married** "second half". She may be able to get a [cohabitating partner variation of B2 tourist visa](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Laws/Memoranda/2011/August/Cohabitating_Partners_PM_081711.pdf) (that will allow her staying up to a year at a time in the US when she comes with you).

Comment: Thanks you for this answer. Do you know if B2 is renewable/extensible ? because my stay could be longer than a year.

Comment: @Apolo I believe she'll have to leave and come back for that, but I'm not sure. I know of couples (gay couples mostly) that used this option and it works.